# Is browserHistory.push() an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, react-router

So here's a case where I'm inclined to imperatively navigate someplace:

Page for a resource has button to delete resource. I want to navigate some other place *only after* resource is deleted, but if the delete fails I don't want to navigate. This requires the ability to say "make delete call, wait till it's done, check what happened, navigate accordingly"

This feels like a code smell to me. It doesn't jive with react-router's declarative approach. Am I wrong?

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this:

```
// this.props.resource from container
<Link onClick={_ => {
  deleteResource(this.props.resource).then(result => {
    if (!result) // don't navigate, dispatch an action
    else browserHistory.push("different/place/entirely") // <= totally imperative
}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing seems necessarily imperative, so I'm not sure you can work around that.

As to whether it's an anti-pattern--I can only opine on what's idiomatic in my own code base, but I use `browserHistory.push` wherever it's more convenient than `Link` (which is often).

That said:  I do think it's peculiar to use `Link` in concert w/ `browserHistory.push`. If there's no routing-related reason for doing so, you ought to use a generic component.

Lastly:  [it *is* an anti-pattern to use arrow-functions in component JSX Props](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md).

Comment: only insofar as ()=>{} declarations are an antipattern in any callback position
but it does fit nicely in a stack code block ;) thanks